# Even and Odd selectors in IE8

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer-8

I'm trying to highlight every second li element. It works fine with other browsers but IE isn't compatible. I tried using JQuery to solve the problem but I'm having issues getting it working.

Right now what I have is highlighting all items in IE8 or less.

This is my code:

CSS

```
    .ms-quicklaunch-navmgr{
        overflow-y:scroll;
        height:650px;
    }
    .s4-ql li.static:nth-child(even){
        background:#CCC
    }
    body #s4-leftpanel{
        width:255px
    }
    .s4-ca{
        margin-left:255px
    }
    .even{
        background:#CCC
    }
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.s4-ql li.static:even').addClass('even');
});
```

This is the HTML im trying to style:

[image]

Comment: There's not a question here. What's wrong? What happens?

Comment: You have a class called "even". You can target that.

Comment: So your jquery has added the class even, what's the issue right now?

Comment: @JoshC I believe this question is about IE8 because he tagged it

Comment: Sorry, instead of highlighting every second li element, they are all being highlighted.

Comment: @Batman in the browser debugger, can you tell what CSS is making the browser render the `<li>` elements the same way?

Comment: @Batman Oh I just noticed your html has a lot of .even classes, the LI parent also has even class so that entire li is highlighted

Comment: I removed the CSS rule. But now it's just a red block. All elements are styled red (I changed the color for a better visual)

Comment: @Batman sorry don't worry about that line, look at my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try updating the jquery to

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.s4-ql .root ul li.static:even').addClass('even');
});
```

currently your jquery targeting is too broad and you have 2 levels of lists

ul.root > li.static > ul.static > li

the last li is the one you need to target but your current jquery targets all of them

Comment: @Batman you are welcome, it is helpful to post some html next time, I am sure this would of been solved faster if the code was there

Comment: Oh sorry, I thought the html image would have been enough. Next time I'll post the code instead. Thank you.